# Homebrew python Install

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I am new to programming and when I install `python3.7` with homebrew it adds two interpreters to vscode. Why is this and which should I be using.

I have installed using `$brew` install python3

```
Python 2.7.10 64-bit  (macOS native)
/usr/bin/python
```

---

```
Python 3.7.3 64-bit
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

---

```
Python 3.7.3 64-bit
/user/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
```

Comment: Are you sure one of them isn't just a symlink to the other?  Try `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3` and see what it links to.

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x  1 master  admin  34 May 22 22:52 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.3/bin/python3

Comment: Ok, so you've found one level of symlink.  Now check the target.  Keep going until you find an actual file.  Do the same with the other path.  See if they're the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `$ which python3` in the terminal and will see the path to the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you issued the below command for installation.
brew install python3

Normally only the latest version gets installed. To install python 2.7, you have to execute the below command. Did you run this?
brew install python@2

Anyway, I'd recommend using the 3.7 environment. However. if you are using this to run a python application which was written in 2.7 version, you should be using that.